# How do I correct input videos that are flipped upside down in blender video edit mode

Tags: import, video-sequence-editor, video

I just decided to give blender a try as a video editing tool. I have around 60 small clips that I want to mix together. I took these with my phone. The videos show correctly in other video players such as VLC. However in blender input panel all the thumbnails for these serries of videos is upside down and when I place any of those videos in the timeline they show upside down as well. Here is an screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

Please show me a way to flip these back to the correct orientation. I hope there is an easy way to do this because as I mentioned there are around 60 video clips that are like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually pretty easy. In the sequencer editor, select your strip and hit <kbd>N</kbd> to display the sidebar on the right. Under Adjust / Transform, check Mirror X and Mirror Y.

However, that will only work for the active strip (the last selected one). If you want to do this with all your strips at once, you can "group" them in a Meta Strip (<kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>), then do the Mirror on that Meta Strip.

Comment: Ok I feel so stupid now. I looked there several times looking for "transform" but did not see it. Thank you!

Comment: As an alternative to meta strips, if you click on Mirror X/Y with +Alt, the change will affect all selected strips. 

Or when you have found the Mirror you want, you can right click and select "Copy to Selected".